# Does the Azure CLI ML "service run" command work?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-machine-learning-service

I have deployed a Model to an ACI container and have an endpoint that I can hit in Postman or using python SDK. I use Python to hit the endpoint as well as Postman and I get a response and the Container Instance logging records the event. I now what to use the AZ ML CLI to run the service and pass in some hardcoded JSON:

[From the Azure ML CLI docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-ml/ml/service?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-cli-ml-az-ml-service-run):

```
az ml service run --name (-n) --input-data (-d)
```

I run this

```
az ml service run -n "rj-aci-5" -d {\"input_df\": [{\"width\": 50, \"shoe_size\": 28}]}
```

There is no output or error. The logs do not record any invocation. Has anyone used the Azure CLI ML extensions to run a service in the manner above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The az cli is likely failing to parse the provided data input. If I attempt to run the same command I see the following error:

`az: error: unrecognized arguments: [{"width": 50, "shoe_size": 28}]}`

You need to wrap the input in quotes for it to appropriately be taken as a single input parameter:

`az ml service run -n "rj-aci-5" -d "{\"input_df\": [{\"width\": 50, \"shoe_size\": 28}]}"`

Comment: Thanks. I have found the problem as to why I get no error code or response. When I run my commands above in a Powershell Terminal, it outputs nothing (I use Powershell to set variables for most of my CLI scripts. However, when I run it in a CMD terminal then it throws the error (or works once I run your version. I am using Visual Code so I switch terminals a lot.... very odd!